# How do I parse E-Mail contents

Tags: perl, email, cpan, perl-module

How to parse the Email into sections like, header, body, attachment, and sender and receiver?
I would like to use Perl or Perl Moose?

Answer (score 9):

see [Mail::Message](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Mail-Box-2.098/lib/Mail/Message.pod) - general message object 
something like,

```
my $msg =Mail::Message->new($mail);
my $body    = $msg->body;
my @to      = $msg->to;
my @from    = $msg->from;
```

or see [Email::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Simple-2.100/lib/Email/Simple.pm) - simple parsing of RFC2822 message format and headers.

**Updated:**

see also [Email::MIME](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-MIME-1.907/lib/Email/MIME.pm) - Easy MIME message parsing.

Comment: The interface of Mail::Message for multipart messages (what jubf calls "attachment") is really complicated to use. I recommend [Email::MIME](http://p3rl.org/Email::MIME) instead which is derived from Email::Simple.

Comment: @daxim: yes, good point, I should add `Email::MIME` in my answer too.

Comment: What is "$mail" in this context? The constructor seems to take a lot of different options, but it's not clear how to just dump an entirely constructed email (a simple string) in to it.

Comment: $mail is a raw mail message, as you can take from maildir, a really long string, no problem.